# Can I enter data(in any form) which will not save in database and only enter for memory in selenium webdriver

Tags: database, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I don't want to enter data into database using selenium ui tests.

```
WebElement templateDesc= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@id=\"description\"]"));
templateDesc.sendKeys("description of test1");
```

Comment: Please explain your problem better.

Comment: if I enter valid data into any input field and submit then it will be entered database,this thing actually working. Is there any way that while doing this with selenium test, data should not enter in database and after closing browser data also be erased.

Comment: You need to talk with the person managing your DB, it has nothing to do with Selenium.